# How to embed Google Ad Sense into React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The question at hand deals with Google Ad Sense specifically but could apply to any script tag insert.   I don't understand how I could add something like this to my component.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                            <!-- My Ad-->
                            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                                 style="display:block"
                                 data-ad-client="ca-pub-24524524"
                                 data-ad-slot="152452452"
                                 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
                            <script>
                            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                            </script>
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Maybe something like https://github.com/yariv/ReactScriptLoader

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69374914/3948601

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A third party script should not be necessary for something like this.

Ad-Sense requires a third party script that looks like this, this should be loaded prior to react and or just put into a template if you're using any sort of template (i.e... django template etc...)

**put this in template:**

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

then take your ad sense include, remove the comment (assuming you're using JSX) and turn what google gave you

**what google gave you:**

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> 
<!-- yourAdname-->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-23452425"
     data-ad-slot="24524524"
     data-ad-format="auto">
</ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

**change it to this:**

```
<ins className="adsbygoogle"
     style={{display:'block'}}
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-23452425"
     data-ad-slot="24524524"
     data-ad-format="auto">
</ins>
```

then put the actual execution code in the **componentDidMount** function

```
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

I would imagine a similar solution would work for just about any of the same circumstances, not just Ad-Sense.

One common misconception is that people often think they can put a script tag in a dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute and that is not the case.  It's using setInnerHTML which will not execute script tags.

Comment: The video is unavailable. Did the solution change or ?

Comment: Thanks @Chris Hawkes - this was just what I needed for a new React site.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the awesome answer by Chris Hawkes, here is the solution adapted for **Typescript**.

After you follow the steps above, you will get errors in `componentDidMount()` because the compiler does not know about the `adsbygoogle` variable and the `adsbygoogle` property on the `Window` object.

To fix these issues:

1. `declare var adsbygoogle: any;` globally (I did it in index.tsx, above all components)
2. In `componentDidMount()`, write `(adsbygoogle = (window as any).adsbygoogle || []).push({});`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use this react component: [react-adsense](https://github.com/hustcc/react-adsense). It supports both Google and Baidu.

Google AdSense gives you the ad code below:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- adapte_ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7292810486004926"
     data-ad-slot="9220497478"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

So how to include it in a react component? Very easy:

1. Write a Component Class, and give it props with `style`, `client`, `slot`, `format`.
2. exec `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` in the componentDidMount lifecycle method.

Then get the [react-adsense](https://github.com/hustcc/react-adsense). How to use it?

```
import AdSense from 'react-absense';

<AdSence.Google client='ca-pub-7292810486004926'
                slot='7806394673' />
```

Before doing this, you should add the `script` in the HTML.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Notice: modify the client/slot with yours.