# How to embed content generating <script> in reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to embed a script tag provided by a third party ad service into my react app. It is like a Github gist. It should run the script and write a `<iframe>` inside the HTML to show the ads.

The official scripts are something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cpro_id = "uXXXXXXXX";
</script>
<script src="http://cpro.baidustatic.com/cpro/ui/c.js"></script>
```

I tried to put the first script tag in the template HTML, and put the second in the component I need it to be, like this:

```
...
componentDidMount () {
  let g = document.createElement ('script');
  g.setAttribute ('src','http://cpro.baidustatic.com/cpro/ui/c.js');
  React.findDOMNode (this.refs.ad).appendChild (g);
},
render() {
  return <div ref='ad'></div>;
}
...
```

Unfortunately, it failed and throw this error: `It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`

I tried [ReactScriptLoader](https://github.com/yariv/ReactScriptLoader) and it gave me the same error.

I tried `dangerouslysetinnerhtml={{__html: '<script src="http://cpro.baidustatic.com/cpro/ui/c.js"></script>'}}`, but failed.

I tried to study the code of `c.js` file and change all `document.write` to `innerHTML=...`, but failed.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell us the version of React you're using and give the complete code of your component because it works in my machine (0.13.3)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am using 0.13.3, too. Does my first tried method work in your machine? Thank you

Comment: I have demonstrated how to include third party JavaScript such as Google Ad Sense located here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282479/how-to-embed-google-ad-sense-into-react-component/30419249#30419249