# using google adsense in react

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, adsense

I have this php script that I'm trying to move to react, and I came into a problem with google adsense.

This is the code I need to convert:

```
<!-- Google -->
<script>(function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){var o={ti:"4027507"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n

<!-- Google Code for Free Trial Lead Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = <int>;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = <label>;
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1048017343/?label=rnLgCPuC2wIQv_Pd8wM&amp;guid=ON&amp;s
</div>
</noscript>

<!-- END TRACKING SCRIPTS -->
```

Is this possible?

Comment: That code is JS, not PHP.

Comment: @Ryan r u asking where/how to load scripts in react based on the route/component being rendered?

Comment: @goldlucks yes I am

Comment: Why don't you add the google script to the end of the body like a usual website? As PHP only printed it at the end of the page, you should be able to add it to your page template or footer

Comment: @Antony it's only required for one page. I'm converting it to a Single Page App that's utilizing react/react-router. I need to put it in the react component for that page. I'm moving it out of php

Comment: You can then add it to this one page's template, add it as HTML and you'll be good to go

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282479/how-to-embed-google-ad-sense-into-react-component