# Adsense ads to react phonegap application

Tags: node.js, cordova, reactjs, adsense

I am using react and phonegap for my mobile app
I install npm adsense

```
npm install --save react-adsense
```

and add google adsense js to my index.html as described here http://yazilimsozluk.com/npm-adsense-paketi and then add adsense component to my project and google adsense ads work in my website.

I uploaded this html to phonegap and generate phonegap mobile(IOS and Android) application but google adsense ads does not show.Should I use any phonegap adsense plugin?Or admob plugin?If yes where should I put this plugin code?In which react component?

And also I want to just install adsense plugin and I want to plugin add ads any suitable component automatically is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282479/how-to-embed-google-ad-sense-into-react-component

Comment: The link you gave is just about react.I did it.But it work for web but not work for mobile(phonegap app)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used AdMob simple plugin. It works well in my apps on both Android and iOS. I tried AdSense but it does not format well on phones.

https://github.com/sunnycupertino/cordova-plugin-admob-simple

This way you have a more native looking ad experience (at the footer of your app, and the dreaded mobile interstitial (popups) we all despise.

Comment: this is ad banner id ( ca-app-pub-9797612634631189/1873349250
  ) but what is  interstitial id ?

Comment: interstitial id is for a Popup Ad. When you setup your ads in AdMob it shows banner, interstitial  (popup), or native.