# How to embed google adsense in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, ads, adsense

I am beginner in reactjs and I want to embed google inline ads in loops. The ad is showing only at first time. When I inspect the element tag shows in loop. Can I please know how to solve this issue?

**Google adsense code:-**

```
 var ScheduleRow = React.createClass({
 var rows = _.map(scheduleData.schedules, function(scheduleList, i) {
  var divStyle = { display: "block"};  
  return (  
    <ins className="adsbygoogle"
        style={divStyle}
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-3199660652950290"
        data-ad-slot="6259591966"
        data-ad-format="auto" key={i}>
    </ins>
  ); 
 });

return (
    <span>
        {rows}
    </span>
);
});
```

**Output:-**

[image: Output Image]

**Inspect Element Output:-**

[image: Inspect Element output]

Answer (score 45):

This seems a duplicated question. You can find it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282479/how-to-embed-google-ad-sense-into-react-component). But I think it isn't 100% clear. So, I came across once with [this](https://www.jamestease.co.uk/blether/using-google-adsense-with-react) blog post which is more clear.

**From Google you have this:**

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
</script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
      style="display:block"
      data-ad-client="ca-pub-12121212"
      data-ad-slot="12121212"
      data-ad-format="auto"/>

<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

---

**Now, in your react app:**

Include the following snippet in your index.html

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Create your react component like:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class AdComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }

render () {
    return (
        <ins className='adsbygoogle'
          style={{ display: 'block' }}
          data-ad-client='ca-pub-12121212'
          data-ad-slot='12121212'
          data-ad-format='auto' />
    );
  }
}
```

Now, to render it multiple times you can simply wrap the `ins` html tag with an iterator like `map`. However, I don't fully understand your need here.

If you want to show them all at once, then do your map like [this](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/iterating-and-rendering-loops-in-react).

If you want to randomise your ad, add a state to your component and a tick state so that it can re-render every X seconds. Check it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39426527/2128873) SO answer

Notes:

1. From you google sense add, rename `class` attribute to `className`
2. Update `style` attribute to be wrapped like this: `style={{ display: 'block' }}`

Comment: sorry for late reply, i'm not feeling well since last 2 weeks, today i'll implement

Comment: i want to show ads in a loop but it shows only first row

Comment: I am doing this same thing. still I don't see ad. I have created a new component for ads and imported this in my Home.jsx file. When I do inspect, in cosole tab it shows error:` Failed to load the resource : ads.js`

Answer (score 6):

If you have the Adsense script loading in one component and ad slot it another, the script might not have loaded while the second component is mounted. Due to this, `window.adsbygoogle` will be evaluated to [] and the ad will not load. This will even affect the auto ads if you are using both auto ads and ad units.

This is the solution I have implemented:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"

const SideAd = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const pushAd = () => {
      try {
        const adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle
        console.log({ adsbygoogle })
        adsbygoogle.push({})
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    }

    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      // Check if Adsense script is loaded every 300ms
      if (window.adsbygoogle) {
        pushAd()
        // clear the interval once the ad is pushed so that function isn't called indefinitely
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
    }, 300)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <ins
      className="adsbygoogle"
      style={{ display: "inline-block", width: "300px", height: "250px" }}
      data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
      data-ad-slot="xxxxx"
    ></ins>
  )
}

export default SideAd
```

Answer (score 5):

Answer by @jpgbarbosa is great. I'll add better practice for Server Side Rendered React applications which have multiple pages, for scalability, I suggest you use this method to keep code base maintainable.

```
export default class HomePage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const installGoogleAds = () => {
      const elem = document.createElement("script");
      elem.src =
        "//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
      elem.async = true;
      elem.defer = true;
      document.body.insertBefore(elem, document.body.firstChild);
    };
    installGoogleAds();
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ins className='adsbygoogle'
           style={{ display: 'block' }}
           data-ad-client='ca-pub-12121212'
           data-ad-slot='12121212'
           data-ad-format='auto' />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use this code as it seems like a nicer way of doing it than adding the script to the index.html file, but I get this error: `'adsbygoogle' is not defined  no-undef`. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably check google ad library is updated? I suggest checking the cdn link

Comment: @AT92 Have you solved the issue? If so could you please share the solution?

Comment: @Foo I was never able ot get this working, so I just went without in the end, sorry

Comment: @AT92 I think you should replace `adsbygoogle = ...` with `window.adsbygoogle = ...`

Comment: @simonelippolis Thanks for this, but one question just to be clear: If you implement it this way you don't have to add the Google Adsense src (async etc.) to the head anymore?

Comment: @Foo no, it's not needed.