# How to implement Amazon Affiliate Link in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-advertising-api

I would like to take the code for a self-optimizing link that Amazon provides through their affiliate programme and implement it into React. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   amazon_ad_tag ="my-user-tag"; 
   amazon_ad_width ="300"; 
   amazon_ad_height ="250"; 
</script>
<script src="http://ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/s/ads.js"></script>
```

This query has been addressed for the Google Adsense implementation code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035999/how-to-embed-google-adsense-in-react-js) but I am struggling to replicate it for the above.

As in the Google Adsense answer, I have put the following script link below into the index.html page but I don't know how to implement the equivalent version of the component.

```
<script async src="http://ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/s/ads.js"></script>
```

Thanks