# Using Script Tags in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to coding and react in general. I am wondering how to get this script(widget) from me index.html to appear in a component

index.html

```
// <div id="cibtWidgetHolder"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
      var widgetHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js' 
      type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='"+ widgetHost + "cibtvisas.com/widget/widgetv2.js? 
method=js&cibtCitizenship=USA&cibtCode=65490&cibtURL=balboa.com&cibtBG=e1f0f2&cibtHeader=1c171c&lang=en&cibtWidgetVersion=3' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
      </script>
```

sections.js

```
  <Col md="3">
  <div id="cibtWidgetHolder"></div>
  </Col>
```

If I call the div in index.html, it renders, but only at the bottom of the page, not with my other content in sections.js

I've seen this sort of usage for others asking similar questions, but am not sure how to implement with mine:

```
const useScript = url => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [url]);
};
export default useScript;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is not something that should be within a rendered section.

Comment: can you clarify? If creating it in it's own component will work, then calling that component in section.js would work, I would do that, but I still fall back to not knowing what my next step is.
Thank you

Comment: You may be able to improve from this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035999/how-to-embed-google-adsense-in-react-js

Answer (score -1):

If you are determined to add a script element to a react app then it may be worth checking out react-helmet or react-helmet-async.

This library will let you add script elements and other meta tags to the html in probably the cleanest way.

That being said there is probably a more efficient way using useEffect or onComponentMount for this process.

Hope this helps